# For which of the following functions, the function can ...

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Please give a hint for this problem. I know that essential singularity may be needed.

Comment: Note that mathematical notation can be "typeset" in Questions here.  See [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and its links to more detailed instructions.

Comment: Hint: Casorati-Weierstraß.